# Проблема с кодировкой Core Data

Tags: objective-c, ios, coredata, кодировка

В консоли по `[[_data.selected valueForKey=@"contact"] valueForKey=@"name"]` из CoreData получаю нормальный текст на русском, но если пытаюсь его вывести таким образом `view.myName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[_data.selected valueForKey=@"contact"] valueForKey=@"name"]` - получаю набор символов.

В чем загвоздка?

Comment: а что говорит дебагер в момент вызова?
т.е. какой тип возвращает [[_data.selected valueForKey=@"contact"] valueForKey=@"name"]?

Comment: @tragvar NSArray

Comment: ну вот, а нужен NSString судя по всему.

Comment: @tragvar а как его получить?

Comment: у вас не ясно что и где. Нужно код смотреть, что такое _data.selected, view.myName?